# Issues using Apps Script getRange().setValues() to populate google sheet with parsed JSON data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am trying to use getRange().setValues() to paste the following data into google sheets using apps script and keep running into various errors (searching these errors gets me nowhere).

The data looks like this (actual dataset is bigger (48 rows, 3 columns):

```
[ { forecast: 81, actual: 79, index: 'low' },
  { forecast: 112, actual: 85, index: 'low' },
  { forecast: 78, actual: 94, index: 'low' }]
```

and I have been using the following code to attempt to populate google sheets:

```
function fetchCarbon() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  url = 'https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity/date'

  let options = {
    "method" : "GET"
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  var parsed = JSON.parse(response)
  data = parsed['data']
  //sheet.getRange("B2:C2").setValues([[data[0].intensity.forecast, data[1].intensity.forecast]])       // Testing populating sheets, this works
  
  var dict = []
  var i = 0
  for (i=0; i<48; i++) {
    dict[i] = data[i].intensity
  }
  
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, 48, 3).setValues(dict)
}
```

I know I could transform the data into a [["column_name_1", "column_name_2", "column_name_3"],["value_1", "value_2", "value_3"], etc.] structure, but considering this data structure is popular with API data, I thought there must be a more direct way of doing it.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: About `The data looks like this (actual dataset is bigger (48 rows, 3 columns):`, when I saw your showing script, you say `sheet.getRange("B2:C2").setValues([[data[0].intensity.forecast, data[1].intensity.forecast]]) // Testing populating sheets, this works`. But, in your sample value, there is no property of `intensity`. From this situation, I cannot understand your question. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the details of your question? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Sorry that was a bit unclear. That part was just a test to extract data from the original structure (I commented it out after seeing that it worked when populating values). That part looks like this:
```{"data":[{"from": "2023-09-19T23:00Z", "to": "2023-09-19T23:30Z", "intensity": {"forecast": 52, actual": 64, "index": "low"}}, ...```
But the real question is how to populate a sheet with the resulting dataset shown in the question (just the ```[{"forecast": 81, "actual":  79, "index": 'low'}, ...}]``` part

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function fetchCarbon() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  url = 'https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity/date'

  let options = {
    "method" : "GET"
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  let data = JSON.parse(response);
  let o = data.map(obj => [obj.forecast,obj.actual,obj.index]);
  o.unshift(["Forecast","Actual","Index"]);
  sheet.clearContents():
  sheet.getRange(2,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried this and for some reason it's saying data.map is not a function

Comment: I'm just going by what you said the data should look like

Answer (score 0):

From your following reply,

> That part was just a test to extract data from the original structure (I commented it out after seeing that it worked when populating values). That part looks like this: {"data":[{"from": "2023-09-19T23:00Z", "to": "2023-09-19T23:30Z", "intensity": {"forecast": 52, actual": 64, "index": "low"}}, ... But the real question is how to populate a sheet with the resulting dataset shown in the question (just the [{"forecast": 81, "actual":  79, "index": 'low'}, ...}] part

I understood that the response value from your API is as follows.

```
{"data":[{"from": "2023-09-19T23:00Z", "to": "2023-09-19T23:30Z", "intensity": {"forecast": 52, "actual": 64, "index": "low"}}, ...]}
```

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function fetchCarbon() {
  // Retrieve values from API.
  var url = 'https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity/date';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var parsed = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  // Create an array.
  var header = ["forecast", "actual", "index"];
  var values = [header, ...parsed.data.map(({ intensity }) => intensity ? header.map(h => intensity[h] || null) : Array(3).fill(null))];
  
  // Put an array into spreadsheet.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, 3).setValues(values);
}
```

- When the value of `response.getContentText()` is `{"data":[{"from": "2023-09-19T23:00Z", "to": "2023-09-19T23:30Z", "intensity": {"forecast": 52, "actual": 64, "index": "low"}}, ...]}`, this script works and the values of `"forecast", "actual", "index"` are put into columns "A" to "C".
- In the case of GET method, `"method" : "GET"` is not required to be used.

#### Testing for creating an array using your sample value

```js
var parsed = { "data": [{ "from": "2023-09-19T23:00Z", "to": "2023-09-19T23:30Z", "intensity": { "forecast": 52, "actual": 64, "index": "low" } }] };
var header = ["forecast", "actual", "index"];
var values = [header, ...parsed.data.map(({ intensity }) => intensity ? header.map(h => intensity[h] || null) : Array(3).fill(null))];
console.log(values);
```

#### Note:

- If you are not required to include the header row, please modify it as follows.

  - From

    ```js
    var values = [header, ...parsed.data.map(({ intensity }) => intensity ? header.map(h => intensity[h] || null) : Array(3).fill(null))];
    ```
  - To

    ```js
    var values = parsed.data.map(({ intensity }) => intensity ? header.map(h => intensity[h] || null) : Array(3).fill(null));
    ```

#### References:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator)

Comment: Thanks for this @Tanaike, I have tried and have got it to work for me too. I guess there's no way to do it without transforming the original structure so that setValues() can access it?

I would upvote, but apparently don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @Sebastian Belcher About `I have tried and have got it to work for me too.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Sebastian Belcher About `I guess there's no way to do it without transforming the original structure so that setValues() can access it?`, in this case, it is required to create a 2-dimensional array for putting the values using `setValues`. So, I proposed the above modification. About `I would upvote, but apparently don't have enough reputation`, in this case, you can accept my answer. By this, other users can see your question as the resolved question.